# React Native - Passing Flatlist items to Modal

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I'm trying to pass a specific item from my Flatlist to my Modal. But whenever I try my output this specific item which is my "price" is not passing although my other states is passing to my Modal properly. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong because sometime, for the sake of trying I delete the other data and just keep the price -- only this item keeping in my code, and when I run and test my output there is still no price that is passed.

Here's my code

**Details.js**

```
export default class Dishes extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modalVisible: false,
      data: [],
      tbl: this.props.navigation.state.params.tbl,
      orderDet: this.props.navigation.state.params.orderDet,
      DineIn: this.props.navigation.state.params.DineIn,
      TakeOut: this.props.navigation.state.params.TakeOut,
      id: null,
      price: null
    };
  }

  fetchData = async () => {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    const response = await fetch(
      "http://192.168.254.104:3307/categories/" + params.id + params.price
    );
    const json = await response.json();
    this.setState({ data: json });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  _onPressItem = (id, price) => {
    this.setState({
      modalVisible: true,
      id: id,
      price: price
    });
  };

  _renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        id={item.cat_id}
        price={item.menu_price}
        onPress={() => this._onPressItem(item.menu_desc)}
      >
        <View>
          <View>
            <Text>Name: {item.menu_desc} </Text>
            <Text>Price: ₱{item.menu_price} </Text>
          </View>
          <View>
            <Text>Available: {item.menu_status} </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <Text>Table No: {this.state.tbl}</Text>
          <Text>Order No: {this.state.orderDet}</Text>
          <Text>
            {this.state.DineIn}
            {this.state.TakeOut}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <FlatList
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          // ...
        />
        <ModalScreen
          modalVisible={this.state.modalVisible}
          setModalVisible={vis => {
            this.setState({ modalVisible: vis });
          }}
          id={this.state.id}
          price={this.state.price} // price
          tbl={this.state.tbl}
          orderDet={this.state.orderDet}
          DineIn={this.state.DineIn}
          TakeOut={this.state.TakeOut}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**ModalScreen.js**

```
export default class ModalScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modalVisible: props.modalVisible,
      id: null,
      price: null,
      discount: "0.00",
      amount: "0.00",
      orderStat: "UNPAID"
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      modalVisible: nextProps.modalVisible,
      id: nextProps.id,
      price: nextProps.price,
      tbl: nextProps.tbl,
      orderDet: nextProps.orderDet,
      DineIn: nextProps.DineIn,
      TakeOut: nextProps.TakeOut
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={this.state.modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          this.props.setModalVisible(false);
        }}
      >
        <View>
          <View>
            <Text>Discount: {this.state.discount}</Text>
            <Text>Amount: {this.state.amount}</Text>
            <Text>Table No: {this.state.tbl}</Text>
            <Text>Order No: {this.state.orderDet}</Text>
            <Text>
              {this.state.DineIn}
              {this.state.TakeOut}
            </Text>
            <Text>Name: {this.state.id}</Text>
            <Text>Price: ₱{this.state.price}</Text> // Here's the price
          </View>
          ....
        </View>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

[Details_screen_shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrtJx.png)

[Modal_screen_shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A01oW.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your _onPressItem function, you have two parameters which are the menu item and price.

However, in your renderItem function

```
<TouchableOpacity
  id={item.cat_id}
  price={item.menu_price}
  onPress={() => this._onPressItem(item.menu_desc)}
>
```

you only pass the item menu parameter to it.

Try this code and let me know if it is work

```
<TouchableOpacity
  id={item.cat_id}
  price={item.menu_price}
  onPress={() => this._onPressItem(item.menu_desc, this.state.price)}
>
```

Comment: it didn't work sir, but I did it with " item.price ". Thanks for the idea, though. :)

Comment: oh okay, it is quite confusing because I saw you have price in your state and also price in your item. I thought you want to pass price in your state because if you want to access item.price, why you need to pass price props separately?